# Choosing components to be installed with Inno Setup using a configuration file

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to program an installer that will install certain programs by selecting a user. Every user has defined assignments which program should be installed.
For now, you have to use the components section to configure the programs. But my goal is to configure it with a text file.
Example for text file could be like:

```
            User1      User2      User3      User4

 Program 1     x          x          x          x
 Program 2                x                     x
 Program 3     x                     x
```

Here is my code:

```
[Types]
Name: "User1"; Description: "User 1"
Name: "User2"; Description: "User 2"
Name: "User3"; Description: "User 3"
Name: "User4"; Description: "User 4"
Name: "Custom"; Description: "Custom"

Name: "Random"; Description:"Random"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "Select"; Description: "Alle auswählen:"; Types: User1 User2 User3 User4  

Name: "Select\Program_1"; Description: "Program_1"; Types: User1 User2 User3 User4 
Name: "Select\Program_2"; Description: "Program_2"; Types:  User2  User4
Name: "Select\Program_3"; Description: "Program_3"; Types: User1  User3 

[Files]
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_1"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_1"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion  recursesubdirs; Components: Select\Program_1; 
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_2"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_2"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion  recursesubdirs; Components: Select\Program_2; 
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_3"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_3"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion  recursesubdirs; Components: Select\Program_3;
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  TypesPage: TWizardPage;
  User1_Button: TNewRadioButton;
  User2_Button: TNewRadioButton;
  User4_Button: TNewRadioButton;
  User3_Button: TNewRadioButton;
  Custom_Button: TNewRadioButton;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin

  { Create custom "types" page }
  TypesPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select User',  ''       ,
    'Please select the right User',true,false);
  User1_Button := TNewRadioButton.Create(TypesPage);
  User1_Button.Parent := TypesPage.Surface;
  User1_Button.Caption := 'User 1';
  User1_Button.Top := 50;
  User1_Button.Height := ScaleY(User1_Button.Height);
  User1_Button.Checked := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 0); 

  User2_Button := TNewRadioButton.Create(TypesPage);
  User2_Button.Parent := TypesPage.Surface;
  User2_Button.Caption := 'User 2';
  User2_Button.Height := ScaleY(User2_Button.Height);
  User2_Button.Top := User1_Button.Top + User1_Button.Height + ScaleY(16);
  User2_Button.Checked := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 1);

  User3_Button := TNewRadioButton.Create(TypesPage);
  User3_Button.Parent := TypesPage.Surface;
  User3_Button.Caption := 'User 3';
  User3_Button.Height := ScaleY(User3_Button.Height);
  User3_Button.Top := User2_Button.Top + User2_Button.Height + ScaleY(16);
  User3_Button.Checked := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 2);

  User 4_Button := TNewRadioButton.Create(TypesPage);
  User 4_Button.Parent := TypesPage.Surface;
  User 4_Button.Caption := 'User 4';                                              
  User 4_Button.Height := ScaleY(User4_Button.Height);
  User 4_Button.Top := User3_Button.Top + User3_Button.Height + ScaleY(16);
  User 4_Button.Checked := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 3);

  Custom_Button := TNewRadioButton.Create(TypesPage);
  Custom_Button.Parent := TypesPage.Surface;
  Custom_Button.Caption := 'Custom';
  Custom_Button.width := 200;
  Custom_Button.Height := ScaleY(Custom_Button.Height);
  Custom_Button.Top := User4_Button.Top + User4_Button.Height + ScaleY(16);
  Custom_Button.Checked := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 4); 

  WizardForm.TypesCombo.Visible := False;  { Dropdown List removed }
  WizardForm.IncTopDecHeight(WizardForm.ComponentsList,
    -(WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top-WizardForm.TypesCombo.Top));  
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = TypesPage.ID then
  begin
    if User1_Button.Checked then WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex :=0
      else
    if User2_Button.Checked then WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := 1
      else
    if User3_Button.Checked then WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := 2
      else
    if User4_Button.Checked then WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := 3
      else
    if Custom_Button.Checked then WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := 4;

    WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo);
  end;
  Result:= true;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not seem to care about the configuration file format, let's pick INI file, as Inno Setup has functions to parse it:

```
[Users]
user1=Program1,Program3
user2=Program1,Program2
user3=Program1,Program3
user4=Program1,Program2
```

---

Then the following script will do:

```
[Types]
Name: "user1"; Description: "User 1"
Name: "user2"; Description: "User 2"
Name: "user3"; Description: "User 3"
Name: "user4"; Description: "User 4"

[Files]
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_1"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_1"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Check: ShouldInstallProgram('Program1') 
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_2"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_2"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Check: ShouldInstallProgram('Program2') 
Source: "TEST \Software\x64\Program_3"; DestDir: "{app}\Program_3"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Check: ShouldInstallProgram('Program3')
```

```pascal
[Code]
function ShouldInstallProgram(ProgramName: string): Boolean;
var
  UserName: string;
  ProgramsStr: string;
  Programs: TStringList;
begin
  UserName := WizardSetupType(False);
  ProgramsStr :=
    GetIniString('Users', UserName, '', ExpandConstant('{src}\UserPrograms.ini'));
  Programs := TStringList.Create;
  Programs.CommaText := ProgramsStr;
  Result := (Programs.IndexOf(ProgramName) >= 0);
  Programs.Free;
end;
```

Type names must be lowercase for this to work. And casing of program names matter.

---

*As the code now actually does not use the `[Types]` at all, you can replace the `WizardSetupType` with direct check to your custom page selection. And you can remove the redundant `[Types]` section and your `NextButtonClick` event function.*